# Minimize on click , Unity Launcher Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, minimize

On Ubuntu 12.04 i was able to minimize windows by clicking the icon on unity launcher with the help of this ppa : http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-get-dodge-windows-and-minimize.html

Now on Ubuntu 12.10 this ppa doesnt work anymore.. What can i do to minimize from the icon ?
Will the ppa be updated or not ?

Comment: The answer lies with the PPA author. [Email him](https://launchpad.net/~ikarosdev) and ask him whether he will update it or not.

Comment: Rather than close this as *too localized*, perhaps we have a canonical question about what to do to get a PPA updated?

Comment: there is a discussion about it on launcpad. Please subscribe in order to increase the heat : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/733349